# Undefined Reference-ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ and was working with OOP concepts.

I created a header file(account.h), a method definition file(account.cpp) and a main file(ex2.cpp).

When, I am compiling the main file, I am getting an error as "undefined reference to".

```
The detailed error is:-/tmp/ccps76QE.o: In function `main':
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to `Account::init(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, double)'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `Account::display()'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `Account::display()'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x134): undefined reference to `Account::init(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned long, double)'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x15e): undefined reference to `Account::display()'
ex2.cpp:(.text+0x178): undefined reference to `Account::display()'
```

.

Kindly help me regarding this issue as I am new to programming and c++

Comment: You have to compile ex2.cpp and account.cpp and link, currently you are only compiling ex2.cpp

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply.
Can you please guide me how to that?

Comment: @RajRajeshwariPrasad E.g. `g++ account.cpp ex2.cpp` Just list all the `.cpp` on the compiler invocation.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. it worked properly. I was stuck in this thing for hours.